# Filter search list won't retrieve results when data is inserted in tables

Tags: html, css

I created a filter search list which is embedded in two different tables.

I want to be able to retrieve the result of the drink I enter in the search box while the headings of the tables remain in place.

For example, if I enter the word "Corona" I want to be see the word corona showing up as well as the heading for Spirits even if there is no matching word under that category.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#myInput {
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:7px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left:45px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left:45px;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius:7px;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  width:30%;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color:#f6f6f6;
  display: block;
}
  
.t1 {
    float:left;
    background:yellow;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.t2 {
    float:left;
    background:cyan;
    margin-left:50px;
}

li {list-style-type: none;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Ingresa palabra a buscar" title="Ejemplo: Cuenta NT">

</br>
 
<table class="t1">
 <tr>
        <th>SPIRITS</th>
    </tr>
 <ul id="myUL">
 <tr><li><td>Armagnac</td></li></tr>
    <tr><li><td>Gin</td></li>
    <tr><li><td>Vodka</td></li></tr>

</table>

<table class="t2">
    <tr>
        <th>BEERS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><li>Budweiser</li></td></tr>
    <tr><td><li>Corona</li></td></tr>
    <tr><td><li>Heineken</li></td></tr>
    </ul>
</table>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i,;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
          a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
          if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              li[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
              li[i].style.display = "none";

          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using table mixed with list? This is a bad structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refaced your code see if it helps you.

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('myInput');
var drinks = document.querySelectorAll('.drink-name');

filter.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
  var s = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  drinks.forEach(function(el,i){
    if(s.length > 2){
       if(el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) < 0){
        el.style.display = 'none';
       }else{
        el.style.display = 'block';
       }
     }else{
       drinks.forEach(function(el,i){
        el.style.display = 'block';
       });
     }
     
  });
});
```

```css
#myInput{
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.list{
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
.list li:nth-child(1){
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#list1{
  background: yellow;
}
#list2{
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Ingresa palabra a buscar">

<br>
 
<ul id="list1" class="list">
  <li>SPIRITS</li>
  <li class="drink-name">Armagnac</li>
  <li class="drink-name">Gin</li>
  <li class="drink-name">Vodka</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2" class="list">
  <li>BEERS</li>
  <li class="drink-name">Budweiser</li>
  <li class="drink-name">Corona</li>
  <li class="drink-name">Heineken</li>
</ul>
```